# Data Model Version Compiler (MOMC) Error in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Hi after I've updated my mac to OS X 10.10(Yosemite) my project won't compile now. :(

I've tried to delete derivedata but still the problem occurs.

Here's the error

> /Users/ronpelayo/loke/Boogiespot-iOS-Library/BoogieLibrary/BoogieSpot.xcdatamodeld: Compilation failed for data model at path '/Users/ronpelayo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BoogieLibrary-ddzzhhrbirmakmgvaskpalwekowx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/BoogieSpot.momd/BoogieSpot 10.mom'

and here's the screenshot of my xcdatamodeId

[image]

I hope someone can help me with my problem I don't know what to do now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the problem is within OS X 10.10(Yosemite)

http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6385584100605952

I've tried to compile my project in Xcode 6.1 and it's running now but I'm still investiging if it has bugs.